# Can I test multiple disk simultaneously? (In disk Utility or a third party program)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, disk-format, third-party

For example, if I have multiple USB drives, an SD Card, an internal SSD, and multiple external SSDs and HDDs connected to a mac, I would like to save time and run First Aid/Repair/Erase/etc. on multiple drives at the same time.

Is there anyway to do so with Apple's provided software or through some third party software?

Comment: Hi @M.Y.Zuo - have you considered trying using the command line for it? `man diskutil`

Comment: @MrR Thanks, I didn’t realize that was possible.